# Epson printer 32 bit & 64 bit policy issue

Tags: android, printing, sdk, epson

We are using the Epson printer in our android application, While we are trying to upload into play store the following error has been created.

```
> "The release is not compliant with the Google Play 64-bit requirement."
```

To convert 64 bit we added

> ndk.abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64'

Then the following error has happened

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.haarisha.epos2_printer-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.haarisha.epos2_printer-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]]
```

Printer Concept works fine for 32 bit but if we changed to 64 bit not working, the above error occurs.

[image: Here I attached error message screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing same issue with brother printer.

My solution :

Create folders 'armeabi-v7a','arm64-v8a','x86','x86_64' under jniLibs and copy the existing .so files, paste it to new folders